# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ahmed Mohamed\fvm\versio'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter

The plugins `flutter_audio_recorder, flutter_statusbarcolor, geocoder, google_api_headers` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH2235 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:661:31: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:662:38: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;
^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:664:29: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:665:36: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:16:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:16:16: Error: The method 'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:23:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:23:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:13:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
abstract class File implements FileSystemEntity, io.File {
^
/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/introduction_screen-1.0.9/lib/src/ui/intro_button.dart:12:12: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'IntroButton'.

- 'IntroButton' is from 'package:introduction_screen/src/ui/intro_button.dart' ('/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/introduction_screen-1.0.9/lib/src/ui/intro_button.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  return FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/country_code_picker-1.7.0/lib/country_code_picker.dart:154:17: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'CountryCodePickerState'.
- 'CountryCodePickerState' is from 'package:country_code_picker/country_code_picker.dart' ('/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/country_code_picker-1.7.0/lib/country_code_picker.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  _widget = FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-1.0.0+1/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:101:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-1.0.0+1/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:33:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-1.0.0+1/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:5:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-1.0.0+1/lib/src/bottom_sheet.dart:299:28: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'VelocityTracker'.
  _velocityTracker = VelocityTracker();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-6.1.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:864:9: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_PinCodeTextFieldState'.
- '_PinCodeTextFieldState' is from 'package:pin_code_fields/pin_code_fields.dart' ('/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-6.1.0/lib/pin_code_fields.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-6.1.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:870:9: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_PinCodeTextFieldState'.
- '_PinCodeTextFieldState' is from 'package:pin_code_fields/pin_code_fields.dart' ('/C:/Users/Ahmed%20Mohamed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-6.1.0/lib/pin_code_fields.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Ahmed Mohamed\fvm\versions\3.7.12\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1157
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ahmed Mohamed\fvm\versions\3.7.12\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to change Gradle versions but it seems to be the same error